# Under what circumstances does gunzip & tar xf work but tar xzf fail?

Tags: tar, gzip

To illustrate the point: I have downloaded the LEDA library from the [company's website](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/free/d5.php). Using tar -xzf on it fails:

```
$ tar -xzf LEDA-6.3-free-fedora-core-8-64-g++-4.1.2-mt.tar.gz 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

However, gunzip followed by tar -xf works just fine:

```
$ gunzip LEDA-6.3-free-fedora-core-8-64-g++-4.1.2-mt.tar.gz
$ tar -xf LEDA-6.3-free-fedora-core-8-64-g++-4.1.2-mt.tar
# no error
```

Can anyone tell me why this could be?- I'd want the standard `tar` command to work all the time.

Comment: What operating system? IIRC there are Unixes with a `tar` that does not implement -z

Comment: @user1129682 From the company's site, it looks like it only has options for Linux and Win...

Comment: If your tar does not support z, use a pipe instead: `gunzip < archive.tar.gz | tar -x` should work everywhere.

Comment: If your copy of `tar` does not support gunzip decompression, you can do the following instead: `gunzip -c $file | tar -x`. It's common to wrap that up in a shell function.

Comment: I just downloaded that archive, and indeed `tar xzf` gives an error, on Debian GNU/Linux (which of course uses gnutar). Odd.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What appears to have happened is that they've *double* compressed the archive.

If you run `file` on your gunzip'd file, you'll find its still a gzip archive. And if you rename it to have .gz again, you can gunzip it again.

It seems recently gnu tar will automatically add the `-z` option, provided the input is a file. So, that's why it works without the `-z` option after you'd already run `gunzip` once, tar automatically added it.

This behavior is documented, from the info page:

> "Reading compressed archive is even simpler: you don't need to specify
>   any additional options as GNU `tar' recognizes its format automatically. [...]
>   The format recognition algorithm is based on "signatures", a special
>   byte sequences in the beginning of file, that are specific for certain
>   compression formats."

That's from §8.1.1 "Creating and Reading Compressed Archives."

Comment: Very well spotted! Confirmed with all combinations of gunzip and tar.